# Is that true If I say posterior = prior multiply likelihood?

Tags: statistics, bayesian

I see a formula that we should also have marginal distribution as denominator. But some tutorial said posterior = prior multiply likelihood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not equal to, but it is proportional to:

$$
\text{posterior} = \frac{\text{likelihood} \times \text{prior}}{\text{marginal}} \propto \text{likelihood} \times \text{prior}.
$$
The reason is that we are interesting in the parameter, say $\theta$, and this parameter only appears in the likelihood and prior, but not the marginal, which is purely a function of the data $x$. In other words, the marginal is just a normalisation quantity that allows the posterior to be a proper probability.

Comment: “allows the posterior to be a proper probability”. Do you mean posterior must be a legal pdf?

Comment: Yes, the posterior is a distribution over the parameter $\theta$

Comment: a good intro is here: https://vasishth.github.io/bayescogsci/book/sec-analytical.html

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your tutorial was referring to posterior and prior *odds* rather than posterior and prior *distributions*, although the equation should then be posterior odds = prior odds multiplied by likelihood *ratio*.

If $\ A\ $ is the event whose prior and posterior odds you're interested in, and $\ d\ $ is the evidence, or data, on which the posterior odds are to be calculated, then
\begin{align}
\text{posterior odds}&=\frac{P(A|d)}{P(\tilde A\,|d)}\\
&=\frac{P(A\, \&\, d )}{P(\tilde A \,\&\, d)}\\
&=\frac{P(A)}{P(\tilde A)}\frac{P(d|A)}{P(d|\tilde A)}\\
&=\text{prior odds}\times\frac{P(d|A)}{P(d|\tilde A)}\ ,
\end{align}
the quantity $\ \frac{P(d|A)}{P(d|\tilde A)}\ $ being the ratio of the likelihood of $\ A\ $ to the likelihood of its complement.